# How can I tag a property in iOS and track it's state throughout the app?

Tags: ios, properties, instance-variables

Is there a way to tag a property or Instance variable throughout the life of the application and see it changes?

The idea would be to see how the property is changed and what class/object changes it's value when that value is passed around a lot?  This way we could see its value every time it changes instead of filling the code with breakpoints.

Comment: you can override the setter and log stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can not tag the property or instance variable. 
But you can make the `Key-Value Observing(KVO)` for properties/instance variables to find the changes of old and new values. `KVO` allows you to observe changes to a property or value.

For example, If you set the observer on particular property/instance variable like this,

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"object.sampleInstance" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

whenever you made the changes on that property like this

```
[object setSampleInstance:@"Hai"];
```

It will call

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    id newVal = (id)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    id oldVal = (id)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
    NSLog(@"KVO new %@", newVal);
    NSLog(@"KVO old %@", oldVal);
}
```

From this you can trace the property/instance variables

Comment: Yeah, which would have the same effect as overriding setters and nslogging. The problem is that following a bunch of nslogs can be tedious.  Thx.